# logits and label must have the same shape)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I am working on my first neural network, and i'm stuck on one error. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
X = pd.get_dummies(df.drop(['variety'], axis=1))
y = df['variety'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='Setosa' else (1 if x=='Versicolor' else 2))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)
print(y_train.head())

from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=8, activation='relu', input_dim=len(X_train.columns)))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(flatten())
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics='accuracy')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=1)
```

I am working off of a tutorial on tensorflow, and am using `https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arshid/iris-flower-dataset` as the dataset to train on. I used the code from the tutorial, but changed it to fit my dataset. Still, I get the ValueError. Any help?
Also, here is the error:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unCE2.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the output from your model is not the same as your labels `y`. Your model is outputting `(N, 3)` and your labels are of shape `(N, 1)`, where `N` is the batch size. You should have your last layer in your model output a single output instead of the three you have in this line:

```
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='sigmoid'))
```